# COM Error: Class not registered (I'm sure it is)

Tags: c++, com, registry

I have a large complex program that has a COM problem.
I'm attempting to write a much smaller [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) program to reduce the problem.

However, no matter what I try, the `CoCreateInstance` in my SSCCE keeps coming back with

```
hr 0x80040154 (Class Not Registered)  (For CoCreateInstance)
0x800706B5: The interface is unknown. (for ICalendarPtr constructor)
```

<strike>I'm using the same GUIDs and other parameters from the bigger program.</strike>
*(turns out I wasn't using the same guids.  Just similar ones)*

I'm linking to the same libraries, and have the same DLLs available (both locally and properly registered in Program Files).

I'm not a Registry expert, but looking through the registry, I do find the Interface and Class GUID look to be properly registered, with a TypeLib-key that refers to a DLL that is present and accessible.

Can you think of something I might be missing that would cause one program to create a COM object successfully, but another to say the class isn't registered?

**Code:**

```
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ICalendar, __uuidof(ICalendar));

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    CLSID classID = __uuidof(ICalendar);
    REFIID iid = __uuidof(IUnknown);
    LPVOID pRet;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(classID, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, iid, &pRet);
    // Result: 0x80040154 Class not registered

    GUID guid = __uuidof(ICalendar);
    ICalendarPtr pDtTm(guid);
    // Result: First-chance exception at 0x773dc41f in COMTest.exe: 0x800706B5: The interface is unknown.


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same architecture? (32/64bit) ? You could always check the registry to see if it is, in fact, registered properly?

Comment: Yes, same physical computer. Compiled with `/MACHINE:X86` in both cases.  My look at the registry does seem to indicate it is registered.

Comment: Duh. Both of these are wrong. You're passing the UUID of an interface, not of a coclass. You either need `CLSID_Calendar`, or whoever the coclass id is of the object you're creating. If your header is available, use `__uuidof(Calendar)` or whatever the coclass that is exposing this interface is actually called. Open the header and look for `coclass`. You'll find it.

Comment: Doh!  The working program has `ICalendarPtr pDtTm(__uuidof(Calendar));`   But I copied `ICalendarPtr pDtTm(__uuidof(ICalendar));` to my program. ***Thank you!***

Comment: Mr Lebeau has it already. no worries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> CLSID classID = __uuidof(ICalendar);

This is wrong.  `__uuidof()` retrieves an interface's IID, not its CLSID.  When calling `CoCreateInstance()`, you need to use the CLSID in the 1st parameter and the IID in the 4th parameter, eg:

```
ICalendar *pRet;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Calendar, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(ICalendar), (void**)&pRet);
```

When using the constructor of an interface smart wrapper, you need to use the CLSID, eg:

```
ICalendarPtr pDtTm(CLSID_Calendar);
```

There is no compiler syntax for retrieving an interface's CLSID.  You have to import the interface's TypeLibrary and then use the generated .h file to get the definitions, or else do a lookup of the Registry at runtime, such as with `CLSIDFromProgID()`.

Comment: +1 Thanks for saving me the keystrokes. Still ashamed i missed it the first time i scanned the source.

Comment: @WhozCraig:   I gave you upvotes on other answers for appropriate Reputation-score. :)

Comment: @abelenky while I'm grateful, I don't recommend you do that. If you come across an answer you find helpful for something you're doing or taking interest in, by-all-means feel free, but not just to stack up a score.